# IIS / MVC application redirecting all outbound WebRequest(s) to localhost (127.0.0.1)

Tags: c#, .net, iis, httpwebrequest, webrequest

Built a simple MVC3 web app to ping a few of our servers for small bits of JSON data and report in a quick UI as a monitoring solution, deployed on Windows 2008 to IIS 7.

All of the outbound HTTP requests via the WebRequest class end up in a error: `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:25946`

Code works fine when running on a console app on the same server, or as console or web app running on a dev machine. Its only when running as a web app in IIS on the production server that this error happens.

The web app can connect to SQL server and MongoDB but fails at any plain HTTP request. Using an empty WebProxy set to **localhost.** (with the period) changes the reported error to a 404.

Comment: Does the web.config of the site contain a system.net section where a proxy (to 127.0.0.1:25946) is set?

Comment: No proxy or any other setting in system.net section. Also tried setting the WebProxy setting of the HttpWebRequest class to null and it resulted in a 404 instead of the localhost redirection.

Answer (score 3):

Try looking at the Host (or LMHost) files and make sure that there are no issues wit them.

Comment: Checked on both files, neither had anything setup. Same results after removing both files.